# IoT Foundation と接続できない

Tags: bluemix, arduino

下記のサンプルを作成中です。リンク先のガイドのうち、ローカルの Mosquitto ブローカーでのテストまでは確認できました。

「Arduino Uno と IBM IoT Foundation を利用してクラウド対応の温度センサーを作成する: 第 2 回 スケッチを作成して IBM IoT Foundation Quickstart に接続する」
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-arduino-iot2/

次のステップとして、サーバー名やクライアント名を指定どおりに変更して IoT Foundation への接続に進みましたが、Bluemix　IoT側の画面で「こちらのMACアドレスは有効だが、データが送られてくるのを待っている」というメッセージが出て、接続がうまくいきません。
上記サイトにあるサンプルスケッチを利用していますが、チェックすべき項目についてご教示下さい。
＜追加＞
なお、IPアドレスは、以下のようにプライベート・アドレスで記述していますが、問題ありませんでしょうか。

> // Note this next value is only used if you intend to test against a　local MQTT server 
>   byte localserver[] = {192, 168, 11, 5 };
>   // Update this value to an appropriate open IP on your local network
>   byte ip[] = {192, 168, 11, 117 };